# Slickgrid add a button to a column

Tags: slickgrid

How can i add a button in a column next to column heading text, e.g.

```
[Father Name] -- heading in column
```

becomes

```
[btn obj][Father Name]
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why you need a button in header? The head converts in "button" when you active sorting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook for what you want to do in slick.grid.js.

If you search for the **createColumnHeaders()** function, you will see a spot where you can insert your button before/after the column heading text.

```
    var header = $("<div class='ui-state-default slick-header-column' id='" + uid + m.id + "' />")
.html("<span class='slick-column-name'>" + [button here??] m.name + "</span>")
    .width(m.width - headerColumnWidthDiff)
    .attr("title", m.toolTip || m.name || "")
    .attr("data",m.id)
    .data("fieldId", m.id)
    .addClass(m.headerCssClass || "")
    .appendTo($headers);
```

All you really need to do is add a property that will have the button code (or some variables to generate the button), and you should be good to go.